# trolleys at heathrow terminal 4

Tags: luggage, lhr

I'm traveling alone from terminal 4 with 3 suitcases and will arrive at terminal 4 drop off in a taxi. Are there trolleys available in the area where the taxi stops? I'm a little worried on how I'm going to move my luggage from the forecourts to the check-in desk if there are no trolley at the forecourt.

Answer (score 6):

Trolleys are [generally available](https://www.heathrow.com/airport-guide/terminal-facilities-and-services/trolleys) throughout the departure concourses and at the drop offs.

Additionally you can always [pay a porter](https://www.heathrow.com/airport-guide/terminal-facilities-and-services/porters) to do so, just a little more expensive but more convenient in some situations.

> Baggage trolleys are provided for your use free of charge in key areas
>   around the terminal buildings.
>
> Arriving passengers will find plenty of trolleys in baggage reclaim,
>   and these can be taken to the car park, bus station or rail station
>   access points.
>
> **Trolleys are also provided on the departures concourse**. Please note
>   that they can't be taken through security control.

and

> Heathrow Porters are available to manage light, bulky, heavy or
>   multiple items of luggage within the airport. Our Porters are
>   stationed ready to help you on the terminal forecourts in departures
>   or in the baggage hall in arrivals, alternatively you can pre-book
>   their services online, by email or phone, bookings must be made no
>   later than 48 hours before travel.